# How to convert date to string and to date again?

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

Hi i want to convert the current date to this format `YYYY-MM-DD`. However, it will convert the date into `String` format, but i want to convert it back into `Date` format. So can anyone advise on this?

This is my code so far

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Date date = new Date();
 String datestring = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: May be this helps [Java string to date conversion][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: Date object has no format, only the string representation of it has the format.

Comment: IMO, Dates should be always stored as Dates and parsing your own Date isn't a good habit. Date formats should be used for user interaction, not for storing the data itself. And if you want to somehow programatically convert the Date to String, using serialization is much more convenient.

Comment: FYI: This Question uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this:

```
 String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd";
 Date date = new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
 String stringDate = sdf.format(date );
    try {
        Date date2 = sdf.parse(stringDate);
    } catch(ParseException e){
     //Exception handling
    } catch(Exception e){
     //handle exception
    }
```

Comment: FYI, while correct this Answer is now outmoded. The classes used here are troublesome and flawed, now supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

Answer (score 4):

Use `DateFormat#parse(String)`:

```
Date date = dateFormat.parse("2013-10-22");
```

Comment: thks! but i would like to auto-generate today's date instead of typing in my own string. How can i do it tho?

Comment: A new Date instance has the current date, just do ``new Date()``.

Comment: You've already got the variable `datestring` in your code.  Just use it instead of the constant in qqilihq's example.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> How to convert date to string and to date again?

```
LocalDate.now().toString()
```

> 2017-01-23

…and…

```
LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-23" )
```

## java.time

The Question uses troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes built into Java 8, Java 9, and later.

Determining today’s date requires a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

If not supplied by you, your JVM’s current default time zone is applied. That default can change at any moment during runtime, and so is unreliable. I suggest you always specify your desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

Your desired format of YYYY-MM-DD happens to comply with the ISO 8601 standard.

That standard happens to be used by default by the java.time classes when parsing/generating strings. So you can simply call `LocalDate::parse` and `LocalDate::toString` without specifying a formatting pattern.

```
String s = ld.toString() ;
```

To parse:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( s ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Can you point me to a source that backs up your "that default can change at any moment during runtime, and so is unreliable." claim? I found this very surprising.

Comment: @omajid [`TimeZone.setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-) may be called by any code in any thread of any app within a JVM *during* runtime. The change immediately affects all other code running in all the threads of all the apps within that JVM. Quite unpredictable and beyond your control as a programmer. Always specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly by passing the optional [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) argument.

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
public static Date StringToDate(String strDate) throws ModuleException {
    Date dtReturn = null;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    try {
        dtReturn = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dtReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Date to String using this function

```
public String convertDateToString(Date date, String format) {
        String dateStr = null;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            dateStr = df.format(date);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return dateStr;
    }
```

From [Convert Date to String in Java](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-common/convert-date-to-string-in-java.html)
. And convert string to date again

```
public Date convertStringToDate(String dateStr, String format) {
        Date date = null;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            date = df.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return date;
    }
```

From [Convert String to date in Java](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-common/convert-string-to-date-in-java.html)